# Meaning of 'Back Home'

Tags: adverbs

Can **back home** phrase mean **back at my place** as in,

> I couldn't find the book in school. Back home, I found it in my cabinet.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence

> **Back home**, I found it in my cabinet.

is structurally correct and understandable, and might be expressed as

> I found it in my cabinet **at home**.

Depending on context

> **back home**

can mean where you *currently live* or where you *grew up*.

> I'm going **back home** for the holidays to see my family.
>   After a wild night drinking, I told my friends "I'm safely **back home**".

Comment: Could there be a difference between "**Back home**" and "**Back at home**" because they are the same to me really.

Comment: I would say "**back at home**" is the specific location, whereas "**back home**" implies the general environment and emotional context. In the case of "We used to have a lot of fun in school **back home**", "back **at** home" would sound awkward.

Comment: Strange, "*We used to have a lot of fun in school **back home***" sounds odd to me. If we are referring to the past than I'd use "**back then**" instead.